# Cannot test the app api due to: ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, categorical-data

I have trained a xgbregressor model that will make predictions by getting data from a website. So to test it I am using postman. When I send data via post request, it shows `ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object`
it also has some backstory:

First I was sending data like this:

```py
{
"data":{
    "enginesize":130,
    "CarName":"alfa-romeo",
    "horsepower":111
    }
}
```

It was showed the following error: `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

then the only solution i could find was sending it like this:

```py
{
"data":{
    "enginesize":[130],
    "CarName":["alfa-romeo"],
    "horsepower":[111]
    }
}
```

and this shows `ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object`

Here's the code for the api:
o_encoder is an ordinal encoder that converts categorical columns selected at obj_col to ordinally encoded values [here's an image of what postman is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPkyX.png)

```py
def predict_api():
    data = request.json['data']
    print(data)
    new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    obj_col = new.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number])
    new[obj_col] = o_encoder.fit_transform(new[obj_col])
    #print(np.array(list(new[obj_col].values())).reshape(1, -1))
    #new_data = o_encoder.transform(np.array(list(obj_col.values())).reshape(1, -1))
    output = model.predict(new, index=[0])
    print(output[0])
    return jsonify(output[0])
```

Comment: Please include the code for getting `request` (since presumably that's where the error messages are from) or the website

Comment: the website is just a blank page that says hello. but it has this code for the predict_api that i have in the question. so here i am just testing if the post req will give the appropriate response

Comment: Yeah but knowing the site will let us test it. btw, do you know which line you're getting this error on?